# count number of rows in an hour using pandas excluding missing hours

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this :

```
               start_time                            end_time                         enter          exit
0      2021-08-02 19:26:50.828000+00:00 2021-08-02 19:26:53.359000+00:00        271       271 
1      2021-08-02 19:26:40.916000+00:00 2021-08-02 19:26:42.216000+00:00         91      91 
2      2021-08-02 19:26:39.952000+00:00 2021-08-02 19:26:42.551000+00:00         91        91 
3      2021-08-02 19:26:36.018000+00:00 2021-08-02 19:26:38.248000+00:00         91      91 
4      2021-08-02 19:26:32.214000+00:00 2021-08-02 19:26:34.316000+00:00         91        91
5      2021-08-02 19:26:30.418000+00:00 2021-08-02 19:26:31.918000+00:00         91      91 
 6      2021-08-02 19:26:22.019000+00:00 2021-08-02 19:26:22.981000+00:00         91        91   
7      2021-08-02 19:26:19.254000+00:00 2021-08-02 19:26:21.283000+00:00        271      271 
8      2021-08-02 19:26:10.421000+00:00 2021-08-02 19:26:13.321000+00:00         91        91 
9      2021-08-02 19:25:49.483000+00:00 2021-08-02 19:25:52.049000+00:00        271      271 
10     2021-08-02 19:25:47.746000+00:00 2021-08-02 19:25:51.151000+00:00        271       271 
11     2021-08-02 19:25:37.188000+00:00 2021-08-02 19:25:39.058000+00:00         91      91 
12     2021-08-02 19:25:27.787000+00:00 2021-08-02 19:25:29.292000+00:00         91        91 
13     2021-08-02 19:25:22.755000+00:00 2021-08-02 19:25:24.257000+00:00         91      91 
14     2021-08-02 19:25:21.789000+00:00 2021-08-02 19:25:24.892000+00:00        271       271 
15     2021-08-02 19:25:21.452000+00:00 2021-08-02 19:25:22.418000+00:00         91      91 
16   2021-08-02 17:54:18.978000+00:00 2021-08-02 17:54:23.283000+00:00        271       271
17   2021-08-02 17:54:05.580000+00:00 2021-08-02 17:54:07.949000+00:00        271       271
18   2021-08-02 17:53:55.951000+00:00 2021-08-02 17:53:58.578000+00:00         91        91
19   2021-08-02 17:53:54.519000+00:00 2021-08-02 17:53:57.081000+00:00        271       271
20   2021-08-02 17:53:52.681000+00:00 2021-08-02 17:53:55.152000+00:00        271       271
21   2021-08-02 17:53:51.447000+00:00 2021-08-02 17:53:54.613000+00:00        271       271
```

which goes on for months of data, but it misses data for many hours and minutes.
I want to calculate number of data/rows hourly for which i am using :

```py
data = df.resample('H', on='start_time').size().reset_index(name='count')
```

This gives me number of rows for every hour, but it also gives the value `0` for the missing hours as it doesnt find any data between that time. So how can i get the number of rows or the size of data hourly excluding the hours which have no data in original dataframe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your problem is solved if you remove the rows with value of 0? To do that you can use .loc, using conditionals:

```
# Keep rows where count column is larger than 0
clean_data = data.loc[data["count"]>0]
```

Comment: You can also simply add `.query('count>0')` at the end of the command